# CSS in React isn't styling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

My CSS doesn't work with my React project, it only changes body (I changed the background color from white to black), the rest from .info isn't working at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import styles from 'assets/css/CSS.module.css';

const Offer = () => (
    <div>
      <div className={'info'}>
        <h1 className={'info__title'}>Pick a pricing plan</h1>
        <p className={'info__description'}>
            We did our best to meet your expectations. 
            Please feel free to pick the right plan for your needs. 
            Remember that in any moment you can switch your pricing plan.
        </p>  
      </div>
      <div className={'container'}>
        <div className={'box'}>
          <h2 className={'box__title'}>Basic</h2>
          <p className={"box__description"}>
             Everything you need. For a reasonable price.
          </p>
          <p className={"box__price"}>$29</p>
          <button className={"box__button"}>choose</button>
        </div>
        <div className={"box box--featured"}> 
          <h2 className={"box__title"}>Pro</h2>
          <p className={"box__description"}>
             More than anyone can give – for less than anywhere else.
          </p>
          <p className={"box__price"}>$99</p>
          <button className={"box__button"}>choose</button>
        </div>
        <div className={"box"}>
          <h2 className={"box__title"}>VIP</h2>
          <p className={"box__description"}>
             Ok, we get it. You’re the boss now. Just tell us what you need.
          </p>
          <p className={"box__price"}>$429</p>
          <button className={"box__button"}>choose</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
);

const HomePage = () => (
  <>
    <div>
    <Offer/>
    </div>

  </>
);

export default HomePage;
```

```
$dark: #171717;
$light: #ffffff;
$font-stack: 'Fira Code', sans-serif;

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font-family: $font-stack;
  background-color: $dark;
  color: $light;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;

  &__title {
    font-size: 45px;
  }

  &__description {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1000px;
  align-items: center;

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.box {
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid $light;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15%;
  position: relative;

  &:first-of-type {
    right: -5px;
  }

  &:last-of-type {
    left: -5px;
  }

  &__title,
  &__price {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  &__title {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }

  &__price {
    margin: 30px 0;
  }

  &__description {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  &__button {
    background-color: $light;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    font-family: $font-stack;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
  }

  &--featured {
    background-color: $light;
    color: $dark;
    min-height: 550px;
    box-shadow: 
      -20px 0 25px -15px rgba(255,255,255, .3),
      20px 0 25px -15px rgba(255,255,255, .3);

    &::before {
      width: 95%;
      height: 97%;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border: 5px solid $dark;
    }

    &::after {
      top: 1.5%;
      width: 40%;
      min-width: 45px;
      height: 30px;
      content: 'most popular';
      font-size: 12px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: $light;
      background-color: $dark;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .box__title,
    .box__price {
      font-size: 60px;
    }

    .box__description {
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .box__button {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: $dark;
      color: $light;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 12px 28px;
    }
  }
}
```

I added the correct code, before that i started writing something else, but that doesnt matter now. details, details, details , details - just wrote this so i could edit.

[image]

[image: Should look like this]

[image]

I've changed css. to scss, imported scss. and installed sass, but the only thing that change is the body background to black
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share actual code formatted as code or a fiddle and not screenshots.

Comment: Have you tried to use `className` in your jsx markup instead of `class`?

Comment: Yes i just did, and it didnt help

Comment: Potentially because you're `import styles from '..'` you are using css modules; therefore your classNames might look like: `<div className={styles.box}>` instead of using a string. You could also change the import from `import styles from` to simply `import '..'`

Comment: Yea i know its my first post, gonna learn THanks to everybody for help, my solution is on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your original post.

**1) jsx className syntax**

Your JSX should look like this:

```
const Offer = () => (
  <div className={'info'}>text</div>
  ...
```

See [codeburst.io/styling-in-react](https://codeburst.io/styling-in-react-5aafecc5edd3).

**2) Specify the correct import**

Your path / filename for the stylesheet should be something like:

`import '../../assets/css/CSS.module.css';`

**3) Add Sass to your project**

> Node-sass is a library that provides binding for Node. js to LibSass, the C version of the popular stylesheet preprocessor, Sass. It allows you to natively compile . scss files to css

Here you can read more about [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

Once you fixed your path, you need to make sure that sass is correctly interpreted.  To make your css (sass syntax) work you need to do two things as css is not scss:

1) Rename your .css file to .scss (yarn will show an error then)
2) Run npm install node-sass (to install sass)
`npm install node-sass` and add it to your project by adding `--save` to the command.

Comment: But is it nicely styled? It shows failed to compile in my case :  ./src/views/Root/HomePage.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/css/CSS.module.css' in 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Projekt Kompetencyjny\PKZ_Frontend\frontend\src\views\Root'

Comment: so it searches in src\views\Root but i dont know why not in src\assets\css\CSS.module.css

Comment: i Used import '../../assets/css/CSS.module.css'; and it compiled but still looks like shit, and none of my styles are actually being used

Comment: Where is your assets folder? try ./assets/.... As I said I got it working.

Comment: that dont work i updated post and pasted a picture of my project tree

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong, spent all day trying to figure this out

Comment: I didnt use yarn, updated as shown in the bash, but the only thing changed is body bg color to black

Comment: I think I have done all I could - start over, do a react and sass tutorial and see if you can get it running. I think my steps are valid. See the latest comment above from @Tom and see if you can get it working with the hint. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative path. Assuming HomePage.js is in components, the import should be `import '../assets/css/CSS.module.css'`
[image]

Comment: it doesn't throw any error with importing css file, but still doesn't work. I added new image